# What is the main reason Amazon Machine Image (AMI)'s i.e. AMI IDs in AWS are different on region to region basis?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

> What is the main reason Amazon Machine Image (AMI)'s i.e. AMI IDs in AWS are different on region to region basis

```
 "AWSRegionArch2AMI": {
        "us-east-1": {
            "HVM64": "ami-0080e4c5bc078760e",
            "HVMG2": "ami-0aeb704d503081ea6"
        },
        "us-west-2": {
            "HVM64": "ami-01e24be29428c15b2",
            "HVMG2": "ami-0fe84a5b4563d8f27"
        },
        "us-west-1": {
            "HVM64": "ami-0ec6517f6edbf8044",
            "HVMG2": "ami-0a7fc72dc0e51aa77"
        },
        "eu-west-1": {
            "HVM64": "ami-08935252a36e25f85",
            "HVMG2": "ami-0d5299b1c6112c3c7"
        },
        "eu-west-2": {
            "HVM64": "ami-01419b804382064e4",
            "HVMG2": "NOT_SUPPORTED"
        },
        "eu-west-3": {
            "HVM64": "ami-0dd7e7ed60da8fb83",
            "HVMG2": "NOT_SUPPORTED"
        },
```

Comment: AMI IDs are regional, not global. When you copy an AMI from one region to another, you have two AMIs, one per region, each with a region-specific AMI ID.

Answer (score 1):

Each AWS Region is independent.

When an AMI is copied to another region, it is a "different AMI". For example, deleting an AMI in one region does not impact a copy of that AMI in another region. This equally applies to the AMIs that AWS supplies.

I see that you are wanting an Amazon Linux 2 AMI. Rather than using a mapping (which can become outdated), a better way is to **use AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store to automatically obtain the "latest" AMI**. This works automatically for the region being used.

Here is an example from [Query for the latest Amazon Linux AMI IDs using AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/query-for-the-latest-amazon-linux-ami-ids-using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/) that shows how to do this in an **AWS CloudFormation template**:

```yaml
# Use public Systems Manager Parameter
Parameters:
  LatestAmiId:
    Type: 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>'
    Default: '/aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2'

Resources:
 Instance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      ImageId: !Ref LatestAmiId
```

See also: [Public parameters - AWS Systems Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/parameter-store-public-parameters.html)

Comment: Thanks @john , my question was to now AWS internals why AMIs have different IDs.

Comment: A closer answer would be: "One can share an AMI from one region to another and then the AMI id may be the same since it'd be the AMI from one region - but for redundancy this isn't best practice." this is not accurate, and AMIs can not be shared, only copied.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simplest explanation is, than when people talk about AWS it implies that it is just one service.

In reality there are many AWS'es and it is one per region (originally they were completely disconnected, now it is a bit more complex). The global services, (for example IAM) typically live in us-east-1 (but that's abstracted from us).

This is why AMI you have different AMI IDs in different region. It is one image per AWS.